# Mint Linux - Downgrade Java to 1.5

Tags: java, linux, linux-mint

Currently, I am running Mint Linux (Release 9).  I need to downgrade Java from version 1.6 to 1.5, and have been trying to figure out how to go about this.  So far, I've had no luck.  The package manager doesn't seem to have it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
- Chris

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  I think it belongs on Super User.

Comment: Which application needs java 1.5 and won't work with java 1.6? Apart from some very small corner cases java is really good at backwards compatibility.

Comment: Java 1.5 is needed for Android development.  I was surprised when I saw this as well, but am not sure of the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @Chrisc are you sure? I've used the Android SDK on Mac OS X and Windows with Java 1.6, it would be strange if on Linux Java 1.5 would be required. Android SDK website says you can use JDK 5 or 6: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: @Jesper Do you mean developing apps for Android?  In my situation, I am editing the Android platform itself.  From what I have found, you must be using JDK 5, as explained here: http://source.android.com/source/download.html

Comment: @Chrisc Oh, I see. (You didn't mention you were working on the Android platform itself...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you explained in your comments, you need JDK 5 because you are working on the source code of Android itself and the [instructions](http://source.android.com/source/download.html) say:

> **Ubuntu Linux (64-bit x86)**
>
> ... JDK 5.0, update 12 or higher.Java 6 is not supported, because of incompatibilities with @Override.

You can do this:

- Uninstall any Java that you got via the package system of your Linux distro
- [Download JDK 5 Update 22](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index_jdk5.jsp) for Linux
- Run the JDK installer with `sudo`, install it wherever you like (for example in `/opt` or `/usr/local`)
- Set your `PATH` environment variable to include the `bin` directory of the JDK

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to downgrade your Java installation to develop for Java 1.5. If you are using a tool such as Eclipse, you can set the project attributes so that it tests for Java 1.5 compatibility, and gives errors if you use a Java 6 feature. If you absolutely insist on having a Java 1.5 JDK then just install it alongside the default installation and use it in place of Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a question for [SuperUser.com](http://SuperUser.com), but my recommendation is to download the 1.5 JDK, and change Java path to where you downloaded it.

Or you could use the info on [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java), it should work for you since Mint is based on Ubuntu. That link explains how to select the version of Java.